# create nested dictionary from specific elements of 2 list of lists

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have 2 lists in below format .

```
fa_n=[['DSS', 'DCCS2K01', 'C9790D0E', '5000', 'SPA9'], ['DSS', 'DCCS2K01', 'C9790D0E', '5000', 'SPB13']]
serv_n=[['10:00:56:00:74:79:0d:0e', '50:02:01:34:36:e4:20:gh'], ['10:00:45:00:74:79:0d:0e', '50:02:01:34:36:e4:20:gh']]
```

I need the following dictionary output wherein the 3rd element of sublist of fa_n will always be the key ,here its '5000'
and this in turn should have a key,value pair of 4th element of fa_n and 1st element of serv_n.

**Expected output:**
    {key:{key:value}, so on }

```
{'5000':{'SPA9':'50:02:01:34:36:e4:20:gh'},
{'SPB13','50:02:01:34:36:e4:20:gh'}}
```

**My code**

```
b_dir=[]
dir_wwn=[]
for arr, fa  in zip(fa_n,serv_n):   
    b_dir.append(f"{arr[3]} ;{arr[4]}")
    dir_wwn.append(f"{arr[4]} ;{fa[1]}")       

print (dict(i.split(';') for i in b_dir)) 
>> {'5000 ': 'SPB13'}
```

So i thought i would create 2 separate dicts and integrate later to one and moreover i seem to be getting the output just for the last value.

Is there an easier way of going about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble you're running into here is that `dict()` (and dictionary comprehensions as well) will favor the last key-value pair it encounters if it runs into duplicate keys, e.g.:

```
dict([(1,2), (1,3)]) == {1: 3}
```

Instead you need to add to the dictionary if it already exists like so:

```
result = {}

for arr, fa in zip(fa_n, serv_n):   
    key = arr[3]

    if key in result:
        result[key][arr[4]] = fa[1]
    else:
        result[key] = {arr[4]: fa[1]}

print result
```

which gives you `{'5000': {'SPB13': '50:02:01:34:36:e4:20:gh', 'SPA9': '50:02:01:34:36:e4:20:gh'}}` as desired.

Comment: Thanks a lot , i am still a newbie to python ,was having trouble appending to dict inside a loop,this seems perfect!